# Как вынести все задачи из GulpJs в отдельные файлы?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, npm

Есть файл Gulpfile.js, который содержит множество задач. Файл уже такой величины, что пришло время его разделить. Я знаю как разделить в GruntJs, а в Gulp нет. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте использовать модуль [require-dir](https://github.com/aseemk/requireDir) (npm install --save-dev require-dir).

*Пример.*
Пусть имеется следующая структура файлов:

- gulpfile.js
- tasks/

  - dev.js
  - release.js
  - test.js

В файлах "dev.js", "release.js", "test.js" содержатся gulp задачи.

Для подключения всех файлов из папки "tasks" в "gulpfile.js", воспользуйтесь следующим кодом:

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var tasks = requireDir('./tasks');
```

Таким образом, все задачи объявленные в файлах из папки *"tasks/"* будут доступны в файле *"gulpfile.js"*.

Если нет необходимости подключать всю папку, можно использовать следующий код:

```
require('./tasks/dev.js');
require('./tasks/test.js');
```

*Использование переменной "tasks":*

Переменную *"tasks"* (объект возвращаемый функцией *"requireDir"*) можно использовать для доступа к экспортируемым членам загружаемых файлов.

Переменная *“tasks”* будет содержать объект следующего вида:

```
{
  "fileName1": {
      "member1": …,
      "member1": …,
      ...
  },
  "fileName2": {
      "member1": …,
      "member2": …,
      ...
  }
}
```

*Пример.*
Пусть файл *“tasks/dev.js”* содержит следующий код:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('dev', function () {
    //TODO: ...
});

module.exports.sayHello = function () {
    console.log('Hello!');
};
```

Тогда переменная *“tasks”* будет содержать объект следующего вида:

```
{
    "dev": {
        sayHello: Function // Функция “sayHello” из файла “dev.js”
    },
    "release": {},
    "test": {}
}
```

И теперь мы можем вызвать метод *"sayHello"* из файла *"gulp/dev.js"*, используя следующий код:

```
tasks.dev.SayHello();
```

Ссылка на документацию:
[Split tasks across multiple files](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил подробное описание.

Comment: @IgnatVilesov Спасибо за ответ. А что делать с полученной переменной tasks? Как мне её использовать?

Comment: @vladiik, Обновил свой ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Я в своих проектах использую вот такой вот gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrench = require('wrench');

wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

Он подключает все js / coffee файлы из директории gulp в которой я описываю таски в нужной мне иерархии.

Пример одного из файлов в директории gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
 //... код таска...
});
```